# Set select default value doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Using Bulma CSS for a little help I made custom component to make me handle different kind of inputs with redux-form.

I would like to setup a default value for a select input.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field } from 'redux-form';

const DropDownItem = ({ spec }) => {
  const { name, defaultValue, items, iconLeft } = spec;

  return (
    <div className="field">
      <div className="control has-icons-left">
        <div className="select is-fullwidth">
          <Field name={name} value={defaultValue} component="select">
            {/* loop for countries */}
            {items.map((country, i) => (
              <option value={country} key={i}>
                {country}
              </option>
            ))}
          </Field>
        </div>
        <div className="icon is-left">
          <i className={iconLeft} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DropDownItem;
```

I have the right value in `defaultValue` but the dropdown doesn't select this value by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `value` of a `<Field />` is controlled by the value in the redux-form store. You should set the `initialValues` for your redux-form form in the config when you initialize it:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

let MyFormComponent = props => {
    const { handleSubmit } = props;
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Field name="fieldName" component="input" /> // this field's default value will be 'defaultValue', as set in initialValues
            ...
        </form>
    )
}

MyFormComponent = reduxForm({
    form: 'myForm',
    initialValues: {
        'fieldName': 'defaultValue',
        ...
    }
})(MyFormComponent)

export default MyFormComponent;
```

You can also pass `initialValues` as a `prop` to your form component.

[source](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-initialvalues-object-lt-string-string-gt-code-optional-)

Comment: Ok so I have to change my stateless component to a class if I want to play with life cycle with the second solution.

For the first one `fieldName` is what I set to name here, right ?
`<Field name={name}... >`

Comment: Yes, what I put as `'fieldName'` in `initialValues` is what you set at `name={name}`.  Also you're correct, to use the life cycle components you will need to convert this stateless component into a class: `class MyFormComponent extends React.Component { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

Seems like `defaultValue` has been disable in `redux-form` according to [this thread on Github](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui#no-default-values)

Instead you can make use the `initialValues` API of `redux-form`

You can read more about `initialValues` [on Redux Form Docs](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-initialvalues-object-lt-string-string-gt-code-optional-) or [initializefromstate](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/initializefromstate/)